How to make sure string length in the frontend is equal to the string length in the backend when using Windows Server?
I have a string length validation in the frontend for a textarea (Using JavaScript).
I also have the validation in the backend (Using Laravel's built-in validation rule).
The problem is that the string length in the frontend might not match the string length in the backend because the server is a Windows Server, so the frontend counts a new line as \n, a single character, and the server sees it as \r\n, 2 characters, which causes the backend validation to throw error that the string is too long, even though it's not in the frontend.
How can I make sure the validation works? Right now I am using Laravel's validation but I assume I will need to write a vanilla PHP validation for that.

Why don't you just replace the PHP_EOL with \n then?

Just count the number of \r and \n. If \r < \n then replace all \n with \r\n.

Windows should be fairly irrelevant here. If the frontend sends text with a \n to the backend, the backend won't magically see \r\n there. Windows programs traditionally use different newlines by default, that doesn't mean every data going through Windows in any way will magically change its newlines.

@DarkBee How? when I output the dd($request->textarea); it's already with the \r\n so I am not sure how to do it. Markus - every new line shows as \r\n in the server side. deceze - But I think in this case it does happen and Windows replaces it? Not magically, but it does replace new lines to \r\n. Olivier - yes, and that's why for every new line in the input it has extra +1 character than it shows to the users on the frontend

The server architecture should not cause any difference as long as you hard-code the EOL characters (i.e., you have "\n" in your source code rather than PHP_EOL). But the client architecture will do for sure. What happens when you hit the Enter key in your browser totally depends on the operating system. If difference matters, just normalise input to whatever your preferred EOL is.

@ÁlvaroGonzález "What happens when you hit the Enter key in your browser totally depends on the operating system." - it shouldn't though; HTML has specified that line breaks entered into a text area, should be represented in the raw value as U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters.

So I am not sure what causes that - maybe Laravel? Because I can't control the user input, I can only perhaps try to count the string manually and look for every \r\n, and replace it with \n, and then do mb_strlen on that?

I can't tell what Laravel does or doesn't since I'm not familiar with that framework, but replacing \r\n with \n is exactly what I meant with normalisation. You can do that in JavaScript so users are provided a coherent count no matter their operating system or browser.

Just to be sure: You are suggesting to replace it on the frontend with JavaScript? Because it counts it correctly with textarea.value.length already, maybe I should do it on the string I receive in the backend? I am not sure how to do that with JavaScript. What you are suggesting is to count the number of new lines with JavaScript, and add them to the textarea.value.length? Something like textarea.value.length + numOfNewLines or some sort?

@ÁlvaroGonzález update: what I did is the following: In the backend, I replaced every occurence of a new line with "\n": (str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r"), "\n", $textarea_input), then when I use mb_strlen it matches the same number of characters that JavaScript counts with .length

If you hit the enter key inside an empty textarea, doesn't textarea.value.length return 1 or 2 depending on the OS? (I don't have Windows here to test but I absolutely had to deal with that in the past while counting chars for a SMS service).

Apparently the value of a new line in textarea depends on the browser and not the OS, that's why the mismatch between what the browser sees and what I get on the backend (1 character with JS and 2 characters on the server with PHP). But maybe that's an organisation-managed version of Chrome and they changed some settings? Not sure

This question is similar to: What character represents a new line in a text area. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@CBroe "HTML has specified that line breaks entered into a text area, should be represented in the raw value as U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters" It turns out it's more complicated than that: see this.

So, to answer the OP's question; just remove \r on the backend.
